# I can't log in to Magento Admin suddenly

Tags: magento, authentication, admin

I can't log in to Magento Admin suddenly.  The error message I get says incorrect user and password suddenly even though it hasn't been changed.  So I "forget password" which triggers the email and then i reset it but i still get the same error message.

I tried logging in from the usual windows desktop at work, and also from my mac at home, just now for the first time and still doesn't go through.

I need to update my work website! Help Please!

Answer (score 0):

you can login to phpmyadmin,  search for  "admin_user" field & click on that and choose MD5 and give new password & save it.

**step 1** : Login to Phpmyadmin & select proper database

**step 2:** : search for admin_user

[image]

**step 3** : click on admin_user

[image]

**step 4** : select MD5 from dropdown and type new password

[image]

**step 5** : click on "Go" button

[image]

you can find detailed explaination [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/reset-admin-password-mysql/) .